# MATLAB doesn't recognise z here

Tags: matlab, debugging

I'm trying to plot $f(x,y) = xsin\frac{y}{2} + ysin2x, 0\le x\le 5\pi, 0\le y\le 5\pi $ on MATLAB. Here's my code:

```
>> x = linspace(0,5.*pi, 10);
y = linspace(0,5.*pi,10);
z = x.*sin(0.5.*y) + y.*sin(2.*x);
surf(x,y,z)
```

I really do not know what's wrong with it. It shows this error:

```
Error using surf (line 71)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.
```

I've looked at multiple MATLAB guides for beginners but it doesn't help. I know I should ideally be able to debug my code myself but I'm a beginner, so I'd be grateful for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the value of `z` for each `(x,y)` coordinate for a surface plot, and hence z needs to be a matrix. In order to do this using element-wise multiplication `.*` you need to have matrices for `x` and `y`. `meshgrid` creates matrices for both your x and y vectors. It repeats the x vector in y direction and vice-versa. Take a look at the following links  - [meshgrid](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [surf](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html).

Note that you need a 2D plane to define a surface, and hence a matrix is needed to define that plane.

So, do the following changes in your code and it should work-

```matlab
x = linspace(0,5.*pi, 10);
y = linspace(0,5.*pi,10);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
z = X.*sin(0.5.*Y) + Y.*sin(2.*X);
surf(x,y,z);
```